# How to make unison ignore all files with .swp extension

Tags: unison

How to make unison (file synchronization) to ignore files with .swp extensions? what should i add on the prf file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See the [manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#ignore)

```
ignore = Name {*.swp}
```

It is important to note that the wildcard `*` will not match files that begin with a dot `.`, so this will not ignore `.swp` files created temporarily by vim. To ignore files with a leading dot in their name you also need the line

```
ignore = Name {.*.swp}
```

You can combine these two lines (ignore all files that end with `.swp` either with or without a leading `.`) and also ignore some of the other temporary files that vim creates (`.swo` and `.swn`) with this single line

```
ignore = Name {.*,*}.sw[pon]
```

Comment: For the GUI users, this is available in the menu under Synchronization>Change Profile (Shortcut: P)>Edit and then you need to add a new preference "ignore" with your Wildcard expressions.